# How to prevent accidentally including old headers?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, header-files, include-path

Build systems frequently have separate build and install steps. Sometimes, installed versions will have headers that are older installed on the operating system and those headers may be picked up instead of the headers in the source code. This can lead to very subtle and strange behavior in the source code that is difficult to diagnose because the code looks like it does one thing and the binary does another.

In particular, my group uses CMake and C++, but this question is also more broadly relevant.

**Are there good techniques to prevent old headers from being picked up in a build?**

Comment: Add version defines, check them.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Add version for every commit?

Comment: @ruslo: When you have every commit in different compiler search paths, then you have a bigger problem.

Comment: @PlasmaHH You can change/remove only one line in CMakeLists.txt or remove just one header file and it is a problem. Note that removing some header file not mean that public API is changing.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Uninstall

Uninstall package from `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` while hacking develop version.

- Pros: very effective
- Cons: not flexible

#### 2. Custom install location

Use custom location for installed target, don't add custom install prefix to build.

- Pros: very flexible
- Cons: if every package use this technique tons of `-I` option passed to
  compiler and tons of `<PACKAGE>_ROOT` to cmake configure step.

#### 3. Include priority

Use headers search priority. See [include_directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3ainclude_directories) command and
`AFTER`/`BEFORE` suboptions.

- Pros: flexible enough
- Cons: sometimes it's not a trivial task if you have a lot of `find_package`/`add_subdirectory`
  commands, error-prone, errors not detected by autotesting.

#### BTW

Conflicts can occur not only between build/install directories, but also
in install directory itself. For example version `1.0` install: `A.hpp` and `B.hpp`,
version `2.0` install: `A.hpp`. If you sequentially install `1.0` and `2.0` targets
some `#include<B.hpp>` errors will not be detected locally. This kind of error can be easily
detected by autotesting (clean environment of CI server don't have old `B.hpp` file from `1.0` version). Uninstall command also can be helpfull.

Comment: By autotesting do you perhaps mean unit tests that detect version differences?

Comment: @AndrewHundt No, I mean clean environment. Build will failed with error: file B.hpp not found.

Answer (score 0):

Guys recently had fixed the exact same problem with shogun package. You basically need to have your source folders including your header files passed by `-I` to `gcc` before the system folders. You don't have to pass the system folders as `-I` to `gcc` anyway.

Have a look at the search path [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html). You might need to have a proper way of including your header files in your source code.

[This](https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/commit/f1006885ccad27456a71d75f014aa918b807cc31) is the pull request which fixed the problem I guess.